# How to work with sockets (state objects)

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

I am learning Sockets, and how to create a code for server and client(s).

(btw, I am doing the asynchronious server and client socket).

What I dont really understand is, when a new client connects to the server, I create a new StateObject. This is a custom class that contains some fields, like an actual Socket and a buffer (byte[] of specified length).

- So do i have to keep on trcking this instance of an state object for as long as client is connected, or I do not need?
- Has the Socket be Shutdown and Closed (these are two methods) after receiving is done, or not?
- How to I create a list of all Clients? Do I have to create a collection of these state objects?

--

I`m asking because I dont really understand the true work of the async sockets, even if I spent a couple of days on it.

What has puzzled (and it still does actually) if when I did create a list of these state objects, and in a foreach loop tried to send the data to each of them at ones (one after another actually), it just did NOT sent.

--

Added:

Would it be enough to keep tracking all the clients with creating a List where T would be a Socket class? What about the state object? Is it only used when data are being passed:

- on server`s side (when new data arives);
- on client`s side (when new data arrives).

Thx in advance for an answer.

Mitja

Comment: Sounds like you're using pre .Net 4.5 APIs. If you value your sanity, consider learning about async/await because it makes problems like state considerably easier to manage.

Comment: No, I dont use anything like it. I am simply trying to work with Asynchronious server and client Sockets. But Iam try hard to learn how all these work - when BeginXXX methods work.

Comment: Notice that the Receive method implements the AsyncCallback delegate, so I don't think you need to explicitly track the instance of the state object. A collection of all the state objects will help you figure out the clients. check [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376313/send-a-message-back-to-a-list-of-clients-at-any-given-time-with-async-sockets-in)